# Failsafe DHCP-relay system

Tags: linux, dhcp

I would like to set up a DHCP-server with 3 DHCP-relays. Is there any way to make this failsafe so if the relays can't talk to the server they can still give out IP-addresses if needed? My other option is to set up four DHCP-servers but then I have four configs to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple configs of *anything* to update, you should probably look at using [puppet](http://reductivelabs.com/products/puppet/) for configuration management and distribution.

Coupled with a good VCS, such as svn or bzr, it's one of the best way to keep configurations equal across multiple servers.

Comment: Puppet looks nice, i will take a deeper look on that someday.

Answer (score 1):

DHCP relays aren't capable of giving out ip addresses. Can you explain your set up in a little more detail? By the looks of it you've got at least 3 subnets, a DHCP relay on each subnet and one DHCP server. Is that right?

Comment: Atm it is all in my head, but yea i got 3 offices who is connected with VPN. My goal is to have one config to do all settings in. The problem i see is if the VPN goes down then no new IP:s will be given out.

Comment: True. The workaround would be to have a DHCP server on each subnet. As you said, then you've got 4 configs to manage. Once DHCP is set up, it's pretty low maintenence so personally I would put a DHCP server on each subnet if I was worried about the relability of the remote sites connectivity. At the end of the day, if the VPN connection or internet connection is down, how much work will the remote sites be able to do anyway? What good is an ip address if you can't connect to the resources you need?

Comment: I think i will try to make a system with Puppet as suggested bellow.